karaf4.1.8 deployed to tomcat 9.0.17.0 met error : Could not resolve mvn:org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.framework/5.4.0
Server version: Apache Tomcat/9.0.17,
JVM Version:    1.8.0_341-b10,
karaf: 4.1.8,
we download code from https://github.com/apache/karaf/tree/karaf-4.1.x/demos/web.
we Extract the downloaded zip and navigate to demos\web.You will find a pom file there.
we Open a command prompt navigate to this directory(demos\web) and run mvn clean install to build the maven project:
mvn clean install
and we put this war into tomcat/webapps ,
and start tomcat by opening a command prompt navigate to the bin folder of tomcat and run:
catalina.bat run
and met error :
contextInitialized
Root: C:\tomcat9\webapps\web-4.1.8-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\karaf
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not resolve mvn:org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.framework/5.4.0
        at org.apache.karaf.main.util.SimpleMavenResolver.resolve(SimpleMavenResolver.java:59)
        at org.apache.karaf.main.Main.createClassLoader(Main.java:458)
        at org.apache.karaf.main.Main.launch(Main.java:255)
        at org.apache.karaf.web.WebAppListener.contextInitialized(WebAppListener.java:45)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4682)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5150)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:713)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:978)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1850)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:773)

can anyone give us some advice ?
We are very anxious.
thank you very much !

This kind of deployment (running Apache Karaf in a web container) is deprecated and should not be used anymore. We are supporting only standalone deployment, is something doable for you?
regards,
François

thank you very much for your prompt reply
